# Hibernate - multiple many-to-many associations between two classes

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities, call them `A` and `B`. Those entities may be in one of three different many-to-many relationships with one another.

How would I model that in Hibernate? The idea is that class A would have fields:

```
Set<B> relationX;
Set<B> relationY;
Set<B> relationZ;
```

And similarly class B would have fields:

```
Set<A> relationX;
Set<A> relationY;
Set<A> relationZ;
```

The two classes both have all three fields, because I want the association to be bidirectional.

Having the "standard" Hibernate many-to-many annotation like this one...

```
@JoinTable(name = "A_relX_B",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")}
)
```

... would not work, as there is no way to differentiate between the three separate relations. How would I achieve that? Or do I need to manually decompose the m-to-n relationship?

Comment: The way you are doing it is correct.

Comment: The way I am doing it? I don't see how the example I gave would work, as I am not specifying the relationship anywhere

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already on the right way:

```
public class A {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "A_relX_B",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")}
  )
  Set<B> relationX;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "A_relY_B",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")}
  )
  Set<B> relationY;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "A_relZ_B",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")}
  )
  Set<B> relationZ;
}
```

Basically, these are independent associations, you can have one (most common case) or a hundred of them as long as each is mapped to a separate relationship table.

The same is on the `B` side (don't forget `mappedBy` to pick the inverse side on each association).

Comment: Really? It will work just like that? It seems I have underestimated Hibernate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an easy way to accomplish this without normalizing the many-to-many relationships out of your tables. Having many-to-many relations in a relational database is typically considered to be a no-no, and would require cross-referencing tables to manage them.

Comment: Yes, many-to-many in a RDB is a no no. However, Hibernate provides a level of abstraction and as such it is possible to map many-to-many with its help. It is done by the @JoinTable annotation, which takes care of decomposing the many-to-many relationship for me.

Comment: I never explored Hibernate very fully so I'm not familiar with all of its features, but in this situation I would say: just because you _can_ do something, that doesn't necessarily mean you _should_. If you had normalized your tables, you wouldn't even have to deal with this problem to begin with, right?

But Dragan seems to have a better handle on this than I do, so I'm going to upvote his answer.